# Send text queries to google assistant Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm building an app with flutter where I need to open google assistant with interpreter mode with a click of a button

I couldn't find any way to do so.

Is it possible to send a text query to google assistant containing " OK GOOGLE, Be my interpreter " which is the query that opens the desired mode of google assistant, if it is possible, how is it done ?

I also found some answers using google assistant sdk but all of them were in python so does that mean google sdk can't be used in flutter ? if it can be used how is that done ?

What about google assistant api what is it exactly for? can something like that be done using it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well. Yes, you can. I did some googling I saw this nice tutorial writing by Marcin Szałek.

This is the [link](https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/). You would have to capture the intent, then handle it in the MainActivity.

Comment: Well the problem is that I want to do the opposite of what is done in this tutorial, I want my app to call google assistant interpreter mode so the intent should be sent from my app to google assistant or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin called - [external_app_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher) . Use the package name as - `com.google.android.apps.googleassistant`

and it will open the google assistant app inside your app. After that, you can speak your query.

[image]